# Static compile a simple executable in MingGW64 under Cygwin

Tags: c, static, cygwin, mingw-w64, msys2

I am trying to compile a simple "hello world" statically linked C program in Windows with MingGW inside Cygwin shell. The program is trivial, is has only one `printf`.

I tried in Linux first, there just the parameter `--static` makes the trick and `ldd` reports that 'test2' is "not a dynamic executable".

```
$> gcc test1.c --static -o test2
```

When I try to replicate the same thing in Windows, with MingGW64 I can't get the same result.

```
cygwin> x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc test1.c --static -o test2
cygwin> ldd test2.exe
        ntdll.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/SYSTEM32/ntdll.dll (0x7ff810290000)
        KERNEL32.DLL => /cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/KERNEL32.DLL (0x7ff80fd40000)
        aswhook.dll => /cygdrive/c/Program Files/AVG/Antivirus/aswhook.dll (0x7ffff5250000)
        KERNELBASE.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/KERNELBASE.dll (0x7ff80de90000)
        msvcrt.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/msvcrt.dll (0x7ff80fa80000)
```

I tried several parameter sequences taken from the Web but nothing seems to work. I attach the image with package i installed in Cygwin at the page bottom.

I have tried the same thing in MSYS2 instead of Cygwin but i get the same results.

[image]

Comment: Since those DLLs are shipped with your OS, why do you care about them being linked? Your users will have them too.

Comment: I would use MSYS2 rather than Cygwin for this, since its primary selling point compared to Cygwin is the focus on compiling non-cygwin programs.

Answer (score 2):

I would not recommend using Cygwin for this, as Cygwin executables will always depend on the Cygwin runtime.

If you want a pure native Windows `.exe` file with no dependencies, use MinGW-w64 either standalone (e.g. from https://winlibs.com/) or from [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/) shell, and use the `-static` linker flag (and if needed also `-static-libgcc`).

Note that you should take care to never mix Cygwin and native MinGW-w64 stuff (object files, libraries).

Comment: Notice that OP is using `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc` rather than `gcc`, so they produce (hopefully) a normal mingw executable rather than a cygwin one. But I agree that MSYS2 is preferrable.

Comment: @Brecht is correct. Plus most windows executables will include the set of dlls the OP sees (except for the virus scanner hook). This is how user mode programs interact with the kernel.